# how to create a numpy list of names from names of numpy files

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of numpy files, they are in one folder.
I need to create a numpy list where I can put in every line some details about each file'name:

Example:
The file name:

```
AES_Trace=300001_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f_Plaintext=f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_Ciphertext=a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
```

Each line in my list must include:

```
300001 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667
```

I mean that I need to put only  numbers then space.

I use this method but it gives all the name of my file.

```
import os
path_For_Numpy_Files = 'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_bin'
path_List_File='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\NewTest.list_bin'
os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
list_files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
with open(path_List_File, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join(sorted((list_files),key=os.path.getmtime)))
```

Hou could I correct it to give me the waited result please?

Comment: `list_files` is a list of the names.  You will need to iterate through that list, and parse out of each string the values you want, and create a new string.  This is just normal Python list and string work.  Not a numpy issue (except for the `npy` extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
 def reformat_name(old):
        key0=  old.split('_key=')[1].split('_Plaintext=')[0]
        key1 = old.split('_Plaintext=')[1].split('_Ciphertext=')[0]
        key2 = old.split('_Ciphertext=')[1].split('.bin')[0]
        name = old.split('AES_Trace=')[1].split('_key=')[0]
        #new_filename =  '{:07d}'.format(int(name)) + '    ' + key0 + '    ' + key1 + '    '+ key2 + '    '
        new_filename = '{:07d}'.format(int(name)) + '    ' + key0 + '    ' + key1 + '    '+ key2 + '    '
        return new_filename

    import os
    path_For_Numpy_Files='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\3_Traces_npy'
    path_List_File='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\ttttttTest.list_npy'
    os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
    list_files_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    list_files_Sorted=sorted((list_files_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)
    with open(path_List_File, 'w') as fp:
        for file in list_files_Sorted:
            new_name = reformat_name(file)
            fp.write(new_name+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the basic idea.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

p = Path('c:/scratch/sample')
for fileName in p.iterdir():
    print (fileName.name)
    print (' '.join(re.findall('=([0123456789abcdef]{2,})', fileName.name)))
```

Output from this script was:

```
AES_Trace=300001_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f_Plaintext=f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_Ciphertext=a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
300001 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667
AES_Trace=300002_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f_Plaintext=f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_Ciphertext=a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
300002 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667
AES_Trace=300003_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f_Plaintext=f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f_Ciphertext=a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667.npy
300003 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f f9f19b259648feb20d842480745de16f a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667
```